# Why does $xg'_x + g(x,y) = (xg(x,y))'_x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Let $g(x,y)$. Why does $xg'_x + g(x,y) = (xg(x,y))'_x$?

I don't understand how you go from one to the other, why are they equal?

Comment: For a given function of a single variable, $\frac{d}{dx} (x f(x)) = x f'(x) + f(x)$ (since $(fg)' = f'g+fg'$). Are you OK with that step?

Comment: What is the derivative of a product? Is not $(uv)'=u'v+uv'?$ Take the derivative of the product $xg(x,y)$ with respect to $x.$

Comment: Can't believe it was this simple. Thank you guys!